# Word Press - Dynamic Content

Tags: functions, customization

I am looking for an easy to manage CMS and Wordpress would definitely meet this criteria. However my website needs to have dynamic process in it.

Within a log-in area, I am planning a process where my clients need to give feedback to certain questions concerning business needs, etc. Based on this input I am planning to automatically display certain proposals within this log-in area from which the client then can choose one or more from. This means that I will have certain rules programmed that apply depending on the user inputs.

Can Wordpress manage such processes? And what would be an easy way to do this?

Appreciate your thoughts on this a lot!

Best regards,

Tom

Comment: Yes, you can do that with WP. The answer to _how_ to do it however, is very, very broad.

Comment: I would start by trying out some different membership plugins to find which one works best for managing permissions as you desire. Then as you have more specific questions, first try to find a solution yourself, then this community may be able to help you more.